# Удаление NA по столбцам

Tags: r

Работаю с csv файлом и хочу удалить все NA значения. Решил написать функцию, которая считывает индексы каждого столбца с NA, а затем через цикл удаляет эти строчки

```
for(i in 1:ncol(rfa)){
 naInd <- which( is.na(rfa[i]) )
for(j in 1:length(naInd)){
     rfa[is.na(rfa[,i]), i] <- rfa[-(naInd[j])]
 } }
```

Однако, выдаёт ошибку. Что надо исправить?

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(rfa, -naInd[j]) : undefined columns selected
```

Answer (score 1):

Для удаления всех строк, содержащих пропущенные значения, в R есть функция `complete.cases`.

Пример использования:

```r
df <- complete.cases(df)
```